# How can I create a proper debian postinst and postrm script?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, packaging

I have tried creating these scripts, the install goes well, however, once the application version is bumped and say I try to upgrade to apx v2.0 nothing goes well.

This is my postinst script

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e 
chmod 755 /usr/bin/apx
chmod 755 /usr/lib/apx/apx.py
chmod -R 755 /usr/lib/apx/data/binaries

exit 0
```

this is my postrm script

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

U_HOME=$(getent passwd $SUDO_USER | cut -d: -f6)
LOG="/var/log/apx"
UHOME="$U_HOME/.apx"

if [ -d $LOG ]; then
     rm -rf $LOG
fi

if [ -d $UHOME ]; then
     rm -rf $UHOME
fi

rm -rf /usr/lib/apx

exit 0
```

Comment: Why do you call `exit 0` everywhere?

Comment: So that if the script executed successfully, it will output 0 otherwise 1.

Comment: `rm -rf` always returns 0 so `exit 0` is not really doing anything there. Actually, the way it is written, this script would always return 0, since [command substitution disables `errexit`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#errexit). I would recommend removing `set -e` and `exit 0`. Instead, it would be good if each command that might fail handles the possible error, for example: `U_HOME=$(...) || exit 1` instead.

Comment: Ahh thanks. Will do it that way next time

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should delete them.

Your `postinst` only sets file permissions; these are supposed to be set in the packaged contents, not in a post-installation script.

Your `postrm` deletes log files, and files inside the uninstalling user’s home directory (assuming it’s uninstalled using `sudo`); both of these are definite no-nos, home directories are off-limits for maintainer scripts, and logs should be left behind on removal (and purge). Your script also deletes `/usr/lib/apx` which is another no-no: `dpkg` is supposed to handle that.

I *strongly* recommend you read the [Debian New Maintainers’ Guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/).